# MySQL stops working every five to six hours

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

My application uses MySQL, on my server, as its database.

My server is highly configured on Windows XP and other on Windows 7. My MySQL version is 4.0.18-nt.

My problem is that MySQL stops working every day after 5 to 6 hours.

The error I get looks like this, in a Microsoft error box:

> mysql.exe has encountered a problem and need to close.
>   We are sorry for the inconvenience.

or sometimes

> mysqld.exe has encountered a problem and need to close.
>   We are sorry for the inconvenience.

or sometimes

> mysqld-nt.exe has encountered a problem and need to close.
>   We are sorry for the inconvenience.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: can you try upgrading your mysql server? it's an open source product and many bugs gets fixed over period of time.

Comment: we are thinking for that. as it our application is running at many palces and database has 400 tables .. it is difficult to upgrade it.

Comment: BDW Thanks for advice....do you know what changes are requires for tables structure to upgrade it to version 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than upgrade if you are running as service you can see if making following change in `Service > Property > Recovery` tab is of some help or not?

[image]

You have to specify restart the service for each instance of failure, if it is not done so far. This can be a temporary solution till you upgrade.

Comment: thanks :) .......it will help a lot.. becouse of this now i have get some time to upgrade my database.still my question is , what changes are requires for tables structure to upgrade it to version 7.

Comment: @Jiten current mysql version is 5.5 for mysql community edition server. I do not think it will require you table changes, what you can do is you can do test migration using mysqldump to export / import database and then test your data. If everything looks okay you can go ahead and do live migration.

Comment: ok...let me check...i get some error with enum type while upgrading.